# How c# code converting to machine understandable code?

Tags: c#, compilation, clr, .net-framework-version

What is the MSIL, CLR, What is the CTS means there are n number of websites that explaining about those concepts and we all know that, but If we want to learn the exact end to end process of source code to machine code conversion process with workflow image, no one explained everything in one place.

So My question here is different from others that we can get the details like Source code to MSIL (Assembly) and then it will be converted to Native code by using the jit compiler etc but when we compile, there is no clear picture of what happening behind the scene and what is the sequence order between  Assembly(.dll or.exe) ILASM.exe, MSIL, CLR, CLS, CTS and all. When these things will be called?.

Could anyone explain the overview of the Dot Net framework source code compilation process step by step and end to end with a sample picture? And I am sure that it will be helpful for all others too who looking total .net compilation process in one place.

Comment: The following webpage is a good reference : http://www.developerin.net/a/39-Intro-to-.Net-FrameWork/23-Components-of-.Net-Framework  Source code (.cs and .vb) modules are first compiled into obj files (intermediate MSIL).  Then the obj files are linked together into an executable.

Comment: It's an interesting research area, but the question here is still just asking for reference material that is definitely already available online. Not sure if on topic for SO.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn-Overview

Comment: @Jdweng I already mentioned, we will get lots of websites, but clear picture & explanations are not there. I will ask my question, let me know the answer. CLS & CTS called or executed before MSIL or after?

Comment: @Nyerguds, Yes materials are available, but that's not in the same page, we have to search one by one because in all pages they explained just an overall process but not explained each step and when it will be called or processed like that.

Comment: @Azzy, that's helpful for Roslyn Compiler but I am asking about .Net managed code process like CLR JIT Compiler.

Comment: So you need this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheBookOfTheRuntimeTheInternalsOfTheNETRuntimeThatYouWontFindInTheDocumentation.aspx

Comment: The Common Lanugage RunTime is the executable.  You are connecting to the websites using HTTP protocol.  So you have a Request and a Response.  The request/responses data formats may or may not be the same.  So you may need different interfaces depending on the website(s).  You still are going to have one executable that supports one or more websites.  Rosyln could be used an interface to the to the websites.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining this is way better using a whiteboard and lots of time but I will give it a try.

**.NET** Compile/Build **=>** Convert **C#/VB.NET** code into **PE exe format** with **MSIL** in it + some trickery to load the .NET framework(**CLR**).

**Windows** only recognizes **PE format** executables. But it cannot run **MSIL** as is. So a **.NET exe** is bootstrapped with .NET framework assemblies (for **JIT** compilation, **GC** etc) as part of the compile/build process. This is a kind of a trick to fool the Windows OS. The OS launches it as a normal process but the control is not handed over to your **MSIL** code directly. Instead it is handed over to .NET CLR assemblies (which are normal machine code dlls). The .NET CLR assemblies then start **JIT** compiling your MSIL code packaged in the **exe** and take over memory and thread management.

This is the missing piece which most novice .NET developers get confused with. So the simple trick is; a **.NET exe** has extra bootstrapping code that gets executed before your **MSIL** is reached. All the remaining stuff like **ASP.NET**, **WPF** is just those **CLR** **dlls** that get loaded. And this is why a **.NET** exe is way slower than a native C/C++ exe.

Your other queries

**ILASM** -> is a tool that can read .NET exe files and display the MSIL it contains. Tools like Reflector can even convert this MSIL code back into C#/VB.NET

**CLR** -> are those assemblies that are bootstrapped as part of the compile process and loaded in memory as needed. Its what is running your MSIL code.

**CTS** -> is just the type system against which you write your code